# How to get the current timestamp from the cursor position for Azure EventHub

Tags: azure-eventhub

I am using EventProcessorHost for reading messages from EventHub. It maintains the checkpoints in a blob storage in the following format

```
{
    "PartitionId": "0",
    "Owner": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Token": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Epoch": 7370,
    "Offset": "12116110271960",
    "SequenceNumber": 106597952
}
```

I want to know if there is a way to find out the timestamp of the events being read using the above information.

I am planning on using the same for creating a simple application that will show the status of read per partition and alert in case the backlog on the partition is growing.

Comment: Which EH SDK are you running?

Comment: "Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.EventProcessorHost" version="5.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the Message Sequence of the *current* message being processed, against the last known sequence number generated for a partition. The difference between these numbers is 'how far behind' the latest message your processing has fallen, and therefore how many messages need to be processed to catch up.

[I wrote an article](https://medium.com/@dylanm_asos/azure-functions-event-hub-processing-8a3f39d2cd0f) that shows how to achieve this using Azure Functions - but the concept would be the same - calculate the number of messages in the backlog using the Message Sequence\Partition Sequence technique & turn that into a metric and record it somewhere. That lets you visualise on a dashboard like Grafana and alert when it breaches a threshold - I use Azure Monitor and a dynamic metric alert to do this. I also use the metric to scale out my processing logic, so it's useful to capture this.